# Can not run Jupyter notebook on Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I just followed the guide in this site to run jupyter on pycharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/running-ipython-jupyter-notebook-cells.html

However, I only get sth like this:

> [I 13:43:45.456 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
>   [I 13:43:45.772 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\ducvt1\PycharmProjects\untitled1
>   [I 13:43:45.772 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
>   [I 13:43:45.772 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8891/?  token=5b3604f38077d1a0fa19dfc9726ab01b682d4ab34fd10544
>   [I 13:43:45.772 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

I hope to receive some help.

Comment: As error explains, seems that the port 8890 is already in use... Did you try with another one? and if you go on 'http://127.0.0.1:8891/' it works?

Comment: Well : After trying killing some ports and it did not work I uninstalled pycharm and reinstalled it. Now I can run jupyter. Anw, tks for ur help

Comment: So the problem was the port?

Comment: Still dont know yet. After trying killing the port without any success, I uninstalled both Anaconda and Pycharm, after that it worked

Comment: If unable to kill a running process (the correct process) manually, then no need to reinstall anything... just reboot. (Note: from the error msg, this is Windows, so rebooting is always a good first guess before (and after) reinstalling.)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ps -aux | grep 8890 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill` to kill the port and try again.

Comment: From the error message, they are running on Windows, so this proposed solution likely wouldn’t be of much help (unless running some type of gnu/bash/Linux util like Cygwin). Rather, they’d use Windows task mgr to kill a python process.